# Can iOS app listen() to a socket?

Tags: ios

Can iOS app listen to a socket to become a server of some kind? If yes, what are limitatoins? Can you connect to this server from outside of your iphone/ipad, can you connect to it from the webpage on the same iphone using the websockets?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, to some extent. Check this topic:

[UDP broadcast using CFSocket on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225143/udp-broadcast-using-cfsocket-on-ios)

What i was able to do was listen to packets sent on broadcast, or to my apps IP address. Then you can just make your own socket callback function that would react to received messages. 
As to limitations of sockets and communication with other devices, most of it is described in Apple documentation.